# Base64 JP2 to JPEG or PNG

Tags: java, base64

hi i have a question how do you transform a base 64 string jp2 to png or jpeg bud i dont need the file image i need the string in format png or jpeg this is my code

```
Datos DA = new Datos();

            DA = (Datos) _output.get(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "Imagen"));

            datosValue = (Datos) _output.get(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("", "Imagen"));

            DA.setFormato(datosValue.getFormato());
            DA.setImagen(datosValue.getImagen());

            byte[] imagenReturnByte = datosValue.getImagen();

            DatosHolder DH = new DatosHolder();

            //DH.setImagen(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imagenReturnByte));
            DH.setImagen(Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString(imagenReturnByte));
            //System.out.println(DH.getImagen());
            System.out.println(DH.getImagen());
```

Comment: Why create `new Datos();` and then just overwrite it with the `(Datos)_output.get` why then assign the same value to `datosValue`

Comment: yes becouse i am use two class in one class iam save the byte image and y the other class iam save the image in a string this is for persistence of data and i need to transform the string imagenReturnByte to jpeg becouse my service he deliver me a data in jp2

Comment: looks like you have to use `jai-imageio` ImageIO from java doesn't support jp2 anymore.

Comment: I’m confused.  Does your byte array contain image data, or base 64 characters?  Are you trying to convert the bytes of an image to a base 64 string, as your code suggests, or are you trying to convert base 64 characters to image bytes, as your title suggests?

Comment: yes i have to convert the base64 (JP2) to base 64 jpeg or png becouse the base 64 come in jp2 format